# Error to upload file to Amazon S3 for a ASP MVC application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Here is the controller. 
I need to upload a image to `AWS S3` but I'm get a error . I'm using the MVC project for asp application.

```
[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Nueva(Historia historia, HttpPostedFileBase HeroImagen)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            IAmazonS3 client;
            using (client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(_awsAccessKey, _awsSecretKey))
            {
                var request = new PutObjectRequest()
                {
                    BucketName = _bucketName,
                    CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead,
                    Key = string.Format("UPLOADS/{0}", HeroImagen.FileName),
                    InputStream = HeroImagen.InputStream
                };
                client.PutObject(request);
            }
            historia.HeroImagen = HeroImagen.FileName; 
            db.Historias.Add(historia);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.AutorID = new SelectList(db.Autores, "AutorID", "AutorNombre", historia.AutorID);
        return View(historia);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

But, when I submit the form get an error.
.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me it look like your AWS related code is not even running.
You get an error based on the line "Viewbag.AutorID = ...", which means, the redirect command above it was never running. For me it looks like your ModelState is invalid.

Note: Please copy your code and exception to your question as text, that would make your question searchable.

Comment: Thanks. I'll Follow your advice